# Return value of () operator

Tags: c++

My last line in my method was supposed to be

```
return methodName(xxx,xxx);
```

but I had it as

```
return (xxx,xxx);
```

The method return type is **bool** and I only noticed the typo when I debug the problem. I did not expect `return (xxx,xxx);` to compile. What did it do exactly?

Comment: not sure how to put in the the correct terminology, but in your example, there is no `operator()`, its just plain brackets

Comment: Comma operator. One of the C quirks, and largely useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Return value of () operator

This is not an invocation of () operator. The syntax of () operator requires the identifier of the function or the variable that is being invoked. Without the identifier, parentheses around the expression are used to group sub-expressions and may change the order in which operations are executed. For example: `1 - (2 - 3)` groups the latter two operands and the result is different from `1 - 2 - 3`. Here is an example where the parentheses invoke a function: `1 - cos(2 - 3)`.

In your case there are no sibling expressions so the parentheses do not change the order of anything and the expression is equivalent to

```
return xxx,xxx;
```

This is an invocation of comma operator, and is similar to:

```
xxx;
return xxx;
```

This is well formed as long as `xxx` is implicitly convertible to the return type of the function.

Comment: imho "Parentheses around the expression are used to group sub-expressions" does not exactly address the confusion OP had, because the function call operator can also be just parentheses around expressions, as in `methodName(xx,xx);`

Comment: @tobi303 I expanded a bit on why this is not an invocation of operator()

Comment: thx, btw it wasnt just complaining for the sake of complaining, I didnt know how to phrase it properly while your explanation now sounds reasonable.

Comment: @tobi303 it didn't come off as being for the sake of complaining. I found it legitimate constructive criticism and I appreciate it. In fact, I had already thought the same thing and was already writing my edit when you commented.

Answer (score 0):

The comma`,` operator will return the last element in the provided list.

`return (a, b, c)`  is equal to `return c`  i.e. its returning last element `c`

Comment: It is not equal to `return c` if the expressions a and b have side effects.

Comment: Of'course a, b & c can be statements but here my intention is only on the return value from the method

Answer (score 0):

`The method return type is bool` is the important point here.

The  primary aim of C++ is evaluating expressions and in

```
return (expression1,expression2);
```

You have two expressions namely `expression1` and `expression2` which are evaluated one after the other ( the comma - which is just a separator - does this bit ).

Since `expression2` comes last, whatever value it is evaluated to is returned. If `expression2` returns a non-zero value the returned value will be `true` and if not `false`.

---

<sup>**Sidenote**: Though `,` can be overloaded it is pretty clear from the question that you're using it just as a separator</sup>